# Can't find a correct regular expression for parsing

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, logic

I'm trying to write my own template engine which gives me the possibility to use something like placeholders inside html.

An example regex I've tried:

```
{:(.+):\s(.*)}
```

It works, but unfortunately not as I want. I'm trying to get the name of the placeholder and it's arguments, preferably splitted.
Here's an example:
https://regex101.com/r/Z7KahK/1

First, it matches "var" and "any_id". My parser looks for a variable named "any_id" and will replace the whole placeholder.

Second (and further) is for example "render". It matches the name of the placeholder and all it's arguments together, which I don't really want. I want to match every argument alone.

For example:

```
Match 1 = render
Match 2 = partial (_order/service_section)
Match 3 = args (myArguments)
```

This placeholder will replace with a new file (provided as argument "partial" with additional arguments ("args") given in this argument.

I'm not really sure if you understand what I'm trying to say, but I tried my best to write it as best as possible.

Comment: Since repeated capturing groups are of no use in PHP, just split the contents of Group 2.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `.*` here. It can [easily skip over any `}` if more in one line](https://regex101.com/r/Z7KahK/2). Better use [negated classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). If there's always `partial` and optional `args` why not use an [optional third capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/Z7KahK/3). If it's arbitrary you need to split as mentioned.